# How can I perform exception handling in MySQL (referential integrity)

Tags: mysql, sql, exception

`MySQL version: 5.6.12`

Hi all,

I have a MySQL database with several tables and foreign keys underneath them. Because of revisioning purposes I need to do a soft delete on a record by filling the the timestamp of deletion in the Deleted field of a table (null means it is not deleted). Now I want to create a trigger that unlinks deleted items if their parent is being deleted. To clarify I have made a small demonstration script:

Table arnold_test.Customer:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `arnold_test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `arnold_test` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `arnold_test`.`Customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arnold_test`.`Customer` (
  `CustomerId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Deleted` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table arnold_test.Address

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `arnold_test`.`Address`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arnold_test`.`Address` (
  `AddressId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Street` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ZipCode` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `State` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Deleted` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AddressId`),
  INDEX `fk_Address_Customer_idx` (`CustomerId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Address_Customer`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`)
    REFERENCES `arnold_test`.`Customer` (`CustomerId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The delete trigger:

```
USE `arnold_test`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `arnold_test`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `arnold_test`.`NinjaDeleteTrigger_Customer`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `arnold_test`.`Customer`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF OLD.Deleted IS NULL AND NEW.Deleted IS NOT NULL THEN


        BEGIN


            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' BEGIN
                UPDATE `arnold_test`.`Address` R
                SET    R.Deleted = NEW.Deleted
                WHERE
                    OLD.CustomerId = R.CustomerId            
                    AND R.Deleted IS NULL;
            END;

            UPDATE `arnold_test`.`Address` R
            SET
                R.CustomerId = NULL        
            WHERE
                NEW.CustomerId = R.CustomerId        
                AND R.Deleted IS NULL;


        END;



    END IF;

END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Now the problem is that when I try to delete a record from the Customer table (by using `UPDATE .. SET Deleted = UTC_TIMESTAMP ..;`), the query fails because of the following error:

```
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`arnold_test`.`Address`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Address_Customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`CustomerId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

When I retrieve the SQLSTATE code with `GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE; SELECT @p1;` the response is `23000` (which references the sqlstate in my continue handler in the trigger). I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I searched the internet on exception handling in MySQL but couldn't find the key answer. Does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks for your help! :-)

Kind regards,
Arnold Pistorius

Comment: have you try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html

Comment: @Varun I have tried that, yes (if you read my trigger script, you saw I have it already in my code). I also tried to catch a SQLEXCEPTION and SQLWARNING, but without the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen to rewrite my PHP script. Now it checks if the referenced field is NULLABLE. If so, it sets the reference to NULL, otherwise it will delete the whole record.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set CustomerId = null because of you have customerid column in address table is FOREIGN key and customer table, customerid column is a primary key and primary key don't have null value.

```
        UPDATE `Address` R
        SET
        R.CustomerId = NULL
```

Comment: This is actually possible if Address.CustomerId is Nullable. But I have a PHP script that generates universal triggers for all tables which are referenced. So if the Referenced field is not nullable, then I want to set the record to deleted instead of the reference to null. I thought it should be possible to 'catch' the error and continue with the alternate script.